# How to disable a php module without phpdismod?

Tags: php, nginx, centos, software-collections

I am using Nginx 1.16.1 with `rh-php73/rh-php73-php-fpm-7.3` on Centos 7.8.

I can't find how to disable a PHP module, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can disable a module if I comment the "loading line" (;extension=exif for exemple) directly in the original file but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do.

```
/etc/opt/rh/rh-php73/php.d$
20-bcmath.ini
20-bz2.ini
20-calendar.ini
20-ctype.ini
20-curl.ini
20-dom.ini
20-exif.ini
20-fileinfo.ini
20-ftp.ini
20-gettext.ini
20-iconv.ini
20-json.ini
20-mbstring.ini
20-mysqlnd.ini
20-pdo.ini
20-phar.ini
20-posix.ini
20-shmop.ini
20-simplexml.ini
20-sockets.ini
20-sqlite3.ini
20-sysvmsg.ini
20-sysvsem.ini
20-sysvshm.ini
20-tokenizer.ini
20-xml.ini
20-xmlwriter.ini
20-xsl.ini
20-zip.ini
30-mysqli.ini
30-pdo_mysql.ini
30-pdo_sqlite.ini
30-wddx.ini
30-xmlreader.ini
```

I didn't find symlinks to these files.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove a symlink from `/etc/php/php_version/fpm/conf.d` directory.

Like `sudo rm /etc/php/php_version/fpm/conf.d/module_name.ini` and reboot php-fpm.

If you need to remove the module also for php-cli, then remove a symlink from `/etc/php/php_version/cli/conf.d` directory.

Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks but there is no symlink in the conf.d directory. Just the www.conf file (/etc/opt/rh/rh-php73/php-fpm.d)